# Display Message if num_rows = 0 in php from mysqli prepared-statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am having an issue trying to get the number of rows from a prepared statement query in php, my query looks as follows:

```
$DBH = getDBH();
$stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT info FROM list WHERE tag = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$tag);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($information);
```

and i basically just want to say if there is no result returned display "no result returned" can anyone please help?

Comment: getDBH is just initializing the connection, it doesn't do anything else.

Comment: I am just trying to get the number of rows returned, when i use $stmt->num_rows; it always returns 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$statement->store_result()` first. Using your code:

```
$DBH = getDBH();
$stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT info FROM list WHERE tag = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$tag);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->bind_result($information);
```

Comment: awesome, thanks so much. very simple fix, and i did not know i had to store_result first. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recognize the class you are using, but generally I do this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dummy WHERE category=13";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
// execute for positive results
} else {
// execute for 0 rows returned.
}
```

Comment: he is apparently using mysqli as a backend, not plain mysql. however you've got right point saying getDBH() is a handmade class and nobody knows it's methods

Comment: well, the problem i am having is mysql_num_rows does not work, i am using mysqli prepared-statements, thanks though.

Comment: its just initializing a new connection, i am just looking for a way to get if any rows are returned, if rows are returned display the information, if no rows are returned, display a different message

Comment: yeah, it depends on what you need to do, but mysqli is the way to go, prepared statements are the way to go to avoid injection.

Comment: @jeffkee, you might want to look at PDO instead. It's DBMS-agnostic, and in my experience a little easier to get working (fewer questions like this one).

Comment: just note, whatever you may be doing with it, PDO doesn't support an SSL connection, but you may not need one.

Comment: you could create prepared statements out of traditional mysql driver as well

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dummy WHERE category=13";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($result)
if($numrows>0) {
// execute for positive results
} else {
// execute for 0 rows returned.
}
```